# PHP Storing a Class in session

Tags: php, session

I have searched and searched and found tons of examples but it seems that everyone has a different opinion about how and when to use session, some use it some say it is evil...

Here is my use case.

I have a Class that has several variables that will need to be used on every page in my application. These variables values are set by making a SOAP call to an API that I am working with. The SOAP call is relatively quick but I am trying to understand how to avoid making a call to the API on every page. I would much prefer to make the call once and then "store" the values somewhere.

I would think that I would just create an Instance of my class on some say Init.php page, make the SOAP calls and then store the whole class in session. Then on all of my pages include the Init.php page. In that page I would do a check to see if the Class existed in the session and if so then pull it form the session.

I know I have to serialize\deserialize the class to do this but I am looking for some feedback here on weather this is the right way to satisfy this use case or if there is a better option?

I am kinda new to PHP, mostly a .NET guys and in .NET the session is generally the best way forward.

All input is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: I wouldn't store the class. I would place the necessary values in an array, encode that to JSON and store the JSON in the session. If you store the class you're storing all of its methods as well, and that seems to be too much overhead. You could also look into local storage.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the data you're wanting to store, so we can get a better idea of the best way to do it?

Comment: @Jay Serializing an instance of a class, u only store the class properties. Don't see much overhead there.

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you stay "serialize\deserialize the class," you really mean you want to serialize/deserialize a class instance (an object) in the session, not the actual class definition. Be careful when using the terms class, instance, and object, since they are not interchangeable and can lead to confusion.

An object can be easily stored in a PHP session. PHP automatically serializes the object at the end of the request and deserializes it when the session data is read on the next request.

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['soap'])) {
    $_SESSION['soap'] = doSoapRequest(); // Returns an instance of your class.
}
```

When an object is serialized, only the variables defined in the class are saved along with the name of the class. When it is unserialized, the class definition must be available (that is, either autoloader or explicitly included into the script). Unserializing will create a class instance with the same data as the object that was previously serialized.